# OpenGL Resize/Stretch on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I currently have an OpenGL view that takes up nearly my entire screen. On tablets such as the Xoom and Galaxy Tab 10.1, there are two many pixels to fill, so since my fragment shader is quite large, my FPS goes way down on tablets. I was thinking that if I resized the view by 2, the shader would have to draw 1/4s of the pixels. But I still need the view to take up almost the whole screen.

So my question is, how do I make a View smaller, then scale it up so that each pixel actually takes up approximately 4 pixels of space?

*I can currently make the OpenGL view smaller by using glSetViewport, but how can I scale it up without making the fragment shader do more work?*

(Stretch to fill screen is not an option because I am not targeting a minimum of Android 3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OpenGL-ES 2 is available (if you're using shaders, it should be) then you can do your rendering to a texture in the color attachment of a framebuffer object in the smaller size (google for "render to texture FBO"). Then you draw this texture to a screen filling quad.